# TINYINT (0, 1) for boolean values in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

as the title states ,TINYINT (0, 1) for boolean values in MySQL return true and false value ,,but i want yes and no value when i retrieve TINYINT (0, 1) values from database. is it possible??

Comment: Why can't you modify them when you retrieve?

Comment: use replace function of mysql

Comment: because i show 1 and 0 numneric value into grid so i display it as yes and no in case of true and false.

Comment: So where's the problem here? You do know how to use IF in mysql? Or in your programming language that you use to retrieve records? Or do you need to be spoonfed for such a trivial task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanting "yes" and "no" sounds like it's for display purposes, and how you choose to format data from your database/models for display should be in your view oriented code and not the database schema nor the query logic, though there are valid exceptions to the latter. Aside from considerations such as whether "first name" and "last name" as separate items could be useful rather than a single "name" field, decisions about database structure should be based on what you need to store and how different data items relate to each other, not on how data is going to look once retrieved. Particularly as you're using a framework, this should be straightforward.

That said, you could use an enum type instead, defining the enum as enum('no','yes'), though cake may still not have support for enums. You can then get and set string values or numeric ones (1 and 2, or subtract 1 to get 0 and 1). Overall though, tinyint with values 0 and 1 is probably preferable as it's conventional and less likely to lead to mistakes/bugs now or in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Use IF:

```
SELECT IF(bool_value, 'yes', 'no') as string_value...
```

Answer (score 2):

tinyint doesnt return true or false. It returns 0 or 1. If you want yes and no, you need to specify that yourself:

```
if($return == 0) {
    return "no";
} else {
    return "yes";
}
```

Comment: $disabled = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
            $disabled->field('IsDisabled')
                     ->title('Disabled');

Comment: i use cakephp grid so how i can add direct condition in,,because i fetch data from controller in json format.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. One way is to add `CASE` to it:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN value = true THEN 'yes'
        ELSE 'no'
    END
FROM
    `table`;
```

Another one, as [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453833/max) suggested, add `IF` option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppModel::afterFind`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
  foreach ($results as $index => $row) {
    if (isset($row[$this->alias]['yes_or_no'])) {
      $results[$index][$this->alias]['yes_or_no'] = $row[$this->alias]['yes_or_no'] ? 'yes' : 'no';
    }
  }  
  return $results;
}
```